# Line plot of rows in a Matlab matrix with the x-axis is the maximum value

Tags: matlab

I am new here and new to matlab.

I have a matrix file in matlab and what I want to do is make a plot of the average all the rows.  However, I only want to plot a few data points (about 20) of the values before, and after, the maximum value within that row.  The matrix file has 550 columns.

I have worked out how to identify the maximum value and the column number of this maximum value using;

```
[maxvalue maxindex] = max(filename, [], 2)
```

As the maximum is never in the same column, i really need help in calculating the average values for each row (before and afer the max value), and then how to plot this where the maximum value would be 0 on the x-axis.

For example - i have a matrix like this;

```
 14    51   623    23     4     1     4     5
 0     0     3     5    67    37    37     5
 0     0     0     0   574     4     5     6
```

and max value = `623
67
574`

and max index = `3
5
5`

So i would like to, plot the average of the 3 rows, 2 data points before and after the max values...so to plot the average of;

```
14, 51, 623, 23, 4, 1
3, 5, 67, 37, 37
0, 0, 574, 4, 5
```

Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = [14    51   623    23     4     1     4     5
         0     0     3     5    67    37    37     5
         0     0     0     0   574     4     5     6]; %// example data
data = data.'; %'// it's easier to work along columns
[~, pos] = max(data); %// position of maxima
ind = bsxfun(@plus,bsxfun(@plus, pos,(-2:2).'),(0:size(data,2)-1)*size(data,1));
%'// linear index into the matrix obtained from pos
data_trimmed = data(ind).'; %'// index and transpose back
data = data.'; %'// undo transpose to put data back into shape
```

Result:

```
data_trimmed =

    14    51   623    23     4
     3     5    67    37    37
     0     0   574     4     5
```

Comment: Sweet idea that one with `bsxfun`! Curious if this would take care of the condition when the max is at edges (left-most/right-most)?

Comment: @Divakar It wouldn't work. But that's a problem with the original question, rather than with this answer ;-)

Comment: @LuisMendo that has worked perfectly for what I want!